# Combinatorics, how many 4-digit numbers include at least one of the digits $4$ or $5$? both of the digits $4$ and $5$?

Tags: combinatorics

how many four-digit numbers include at least one of the digits 4 or 5?
b, how many four-digit numbers include both the digits 4 and 5?

So, all of the possibilities: 9x10x10x10=9000

neither 5 nor 4: 7x8x8x8=3584

at least 4 or 5: 9000-3584 = 5416

Comment: Are you asking how many four-digit numbers include at least one of the digits $4$ or $5$?  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and to explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thank you, that you corrected my grammar. :) I am from Hungary.

Comment: Maybe the culture is different but here it is frowned upon when you ask someone else to do your work for you. If you could tell us what you tried and where you are stuck then perhaps we can be of help.

Comment: Sorry, I added some things to it. I was thinking about it a lot. But I am confused.

Comment: The number of four-digit numbers that include at least one of the digits can be found by subtracting the number of four-digit numbers which contain neither $4$ nor $5$ from the total number of four-digit numbers.  For instance, there are $90 - 56 = 34$ two-digit numbers which contain at least one of the digits $4$ or $5$.  For the second problem, try using an inclusion-exclusion argument.

Comment: Do you now understand how to solve the first question?

Comment: If you now understand the first question, you should update your question to reflect your revised answer and explain where you are stuck on the second question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How many four-digit numbers include at least one of the digits $4$ or $5$?

The number of four-digit numbers that include at least one of the digits $4$ or $5$ is found by subtracting the number of four-digit numbers with neither a $4$ nor a $5$ from the number of four-digit numbers.

There are $9 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 \cdot 10$ four-digit numbers since the thousands place can be filled with any of the ten digits in the decimal system except zero and each of the other places can be filled by any of the $10$ digits in the decimal system.

There are $7 \cdot 8 \cdot 8 \cdot 8$ four-digit numbers in which neither of the digits $4$ nor $5$ appear since there are seven ways to fill the thousands place with a digit other than $0$, $4$, or $5$ and eight ways to fill each of the remaining places with a digit other than $4$ or $5$.

Therefore, as you found, the number of four-digit numbers in which at least one of the digits $4$ or $5$ appears is
$$9 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 - 7 \cdot 8 \cdot 8 \cdot 8 = 9000 - 3584 = 5416$$

> How many four-digit numbers include both of the digits $4$ and $5$?

To find the number of four-digit numbers which include both of the digits $4$ and $5$, we must subtract the number of four-digit numbers which do not include the digit $4$ or do not include the digit $5$ from the number of four-digit numbers.

As you showed above, there are $9 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 = 9000$ four-digit numbers.  Of these, $8 \cdot 9 \cdot 9 \cdot 9$ do not include the digit $4$ since there are eight ways to fill the thousands place with a digit other than $0$ or $4$ and there are $9$ ways to fill each of the other places with a digit other than $4$.  By symmetry, there are $8 \cdot 9 \cdot 9 \cdot 9$ four-digit numbers in which the digit $5$ does not appear.  However, if we subtract $2 \cdot 8 \cdot 9 \cdot 9 \cdot 9$ from $9 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 \cdot 10$, we will have subtracted too much.  This is because we will have subtracted each number in which neither $4$ nor $5$ appears twice, once when we subtracted those four-digit numbers in which the digit $4$ does not appear and once when we subtracted those four-digit numbers in which the digit $5$ does not appear.  We only want to subtract such numbers once, so we must add them to the total.  You showed above that there are $7 \cdot 8 \cdot 8 \cdot 8$ four-digit numbers in which neither of the digits $4$ nor $5$ appears.  Hence, by the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), there are
$$9 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 \cdot 10 - 2 \cdot 8 \cdot 9 \cdot 9 \cdot 9 + 7 \cdot 8 \cdot 8 \cdot 8 = 9000 - 2 \cdot 5832 + 3584 = 920$$
four-digit numbers in which both the digits $4$ and $5$ appear.

More formally, if we let $U$ be the set of all four-digit numbers, $A$ be the set of four-digit numbers in which $4$ appears, and $B$ be the set of four-digit numbers in which $5$ appears.  Then
the number of four-digit numbers in which both the digits $4$ and $5$ appear is
\begin{align*}
|A \cap B| & = |U| - |A' \cup B'|\\
           & = |U| - (|A'| + |B'| - |A' \cap B'|)\\
           & = |U| - |A'| + |B'| + |A' \cap B'|\\
           & = 9000 - 5832 - 5832 + 3584\\
           & = 920 
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you so much!! I really appreciate it. I just started learn math again, just for fun. I finally got it. It is actually not hard, but I haven't done math since years.